# nontech newbie trying to learn terminology

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

Do I have to become a computer geek if I want to use Ubuntu? Script? root administrator? bin? lib? proc? opt? Headache!!! Then, when I click on one of those folders, trying to educate myself... sh*t a brick confusion. I have no clue what I'm doing. I even get lost when I read the Ubuntu Guide because it starts using tech words for which I have no foundation. I need explanations, like "the root administrator does XXXX", "the bin is where you throw your garbage". I can't even find a search option to find programs. help... I'm not even sure what version I have. I think it's the newest, cuz the guy who installed this for me a about 2 months ago said it was fairly new...

Comment: I feel your pain and I've been doing Unix for years (although I don't have trouble with bin, lib, proc, etc.) Having to learn about Linux Desktops, themes, GNOME vs Unity, and a 100 other 'branded' names for generic technologies has been "a learning opportunity". BUT sorry to say, Linux is a complex system, if you want to (not even) master it, it will take some time. There are many tutorials for Linux, so take some time, and find out which tutorials work for you. It may also help if you have specialty you want to work in (graphics, sound, or ??) to find a specialized Linux version for that.

Comment: Many community colleges have a Unix/Linux class. Or look at your library, our's has a dozen different Linux For Everyone sort of books. Take your time and work thru one or two of them. Once you understand one Linux system, the variations will start to make sense. If that doesn't work for you, ask around with your geek friends for a tour through their Linux. If your town/city has a craigslist, put up an offer for $$ or swap of services under Jobs->computer->computerGigs. And, sorry to say, I'd expect this question to be closed here as 'too broad'. Read the FAQ about good questions. Good luck!

Comment: My specialty is being a mom, homeschooling, writing/Blogging/citizen journalist/activist who likes to watch Netflix, etc., and doesn't wanna get a lot of STD's watching from other sites, nor have the govt snooping in on me too much. So much for my theatre degree. Thanks! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lol, same happened to me 4-5 years ago when I first heard about Linux. My head still hurts while reading some guides and stuff like that :D
Well, first, you have to learn terminology... whats what. Like, for example, root administrator is the absolute owner of that OS (stands for Operating System, like Windows 7, Ubuntu etc.). Therefore, root administrator can do everything on (install, uninstall, delete system files, modify them and so on). Normal users cant. It's like Administrator on Windows. Now, how I learned all that is by simply googling that what I didn't understand or knew. So, just now I typed Linux terminology and this is what came up: [Is Linux Confusing?](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-confusing-key-terms-definitions/)

After you lean all that terminology you will have the foundation for reading some articles on the web about Linux, how it works, whats the difference between Windows and Linux and so on. And how to find those articles? Google is you best friend ;)

Do you have to become a geek to use Ubuntu? Nope :) You just have to familiarize yourself with it, just like you did with Windows, Androind on your mobile phone, navigation in your car... Or maybe you could ask that same guy that installed it for you to tell you some basics of Ubuntu, and Linux itself.

In any case, have fun! :D

Comment: Thanks so much, I've bookmarked the link you gave me. Who says a 48 yr old mom with a past degree in theatre/lib arts can't be a tech geek, right?

Comment: 'Is Linux Confusing' is super helpful! Can't upvote you much more. Will check back next week ;-).